# mod_rewrite remove url component

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I specify a .htaccess condition that rewrites the following url:

```
http://test.com/files/js/version345/user.js
```

to

```
http://test.com/files/js/user.js
```

Here the version number is incremented, i.e. version346, version347 etc.

I'd like to do this as a more reliable way of forcing browsers to get updated javascript files when they ignore query parameters and MAX-AGE http headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(files/js)/version\d+/(.+\.js)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC]
```